# How to combine Maven Build and Docker in Github Actions?

Tags: docker, maven, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I am attempting the following process in GitHub Actions:

1. Build a .war file using maven (successful)
2. Upload the .war file to a local repository (successful)
3. Prepare docker (Successful)
4. Run docker build and push, including .war file (unsuccessful)

So far I have attempted:

- Retrieving the uploaded artifact (as seen in the code below) and unzipping it

  - This fails, with Docker unable to find the uploaded artifact
- Building the .war file and uploading it in one job, then downloading it in a subsequent using actions/download-artifact@v3 as described [here](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/share-image-jobs.md).

  - This fails, with Docker unable to find the .war file
- In a single job, building the and .war file copying it to the same directory as the Dockerfile, while using Checkout in a previous step and specifying the Docker context as . as mentioned in the git context segment of [this page](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action).

  - This fails, with Docker unable to find the .war file
- Copying the war file directly to the docker runtime directory for Docker to use

  - This fails due to a permissions error
- Copying both the Dockerfile and the .war file to /tmp, then running docker in the /tmp/ context (i.e. /tmp/ or /),

  - This fails, with Docker unable to find the .war file

The relevant segment of my github actions ./yml file is as follows:

```
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn --settings server/mvn_settings/settings.xml --batch-mode --update-snapshots -f server/pom.xml -Drepo.login=${{ #### }} -Drepo.password=${{ #### }} COMPONENT
        
      - name: Copy files to neccessary folders
        run: mkdir staging && cp server/COMPONENT/target/*.war staging
      
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
         name: COMPONENT
         path: staging
         
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
        
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
        
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: COMPONENT
          path: .
        
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ####
          password: ####
        
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/app:latestjobs:
```

Relevant portion of my Dockerfile is below:

```
RUN unzip -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/APPLICATION/ COMPONENT
```

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for the very detailed question. It would be good to show some logs though and narrow down the YAML to a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile as well?